# Low perfomance of coping one table to another using Spark + Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to copy one table to another using spark + spark-cassandra-connector and it takes very much time(~ 17 hours). Even for simple counting all rows(~ 2 billions) i spend about 1 hour.
How can i speed up this process? 
**Cassandra version: 3.1**

```
object Init {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "host")
//      .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "16")
//      .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
      .setAppName("spark2Cassandra")
      .setMaster("local[*]")

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val table = sparkContext.cassandraTable("testkeyspace", "test_5")
    table.saveToCassandra("testkeyspace", "test_4")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using "local" mode for your Spark application. This means you are running your application on a single machine. This usually means you don't need Spark. To increase performance I would consider adding more nodes (so more clients would be in action.)

If you still have issues it's best to try to determine your actual bottleneck in the system and then try to widen that. At the moment it's likely that the issue is that you are using a single machine.

Comment: Like I said it could be dependent on many things and you need to actually look at your os metrics to determine the bottleneck.